# Showing that for $x \ge 7$, $x\# \ge x^2+x$

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers, primorial

Let $x\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) of $x$.

I am trying to show that if $x \ge 7$:

> $$x\# \ge x^2+x$$

Is there a straight forward argument?

Here's what I came up with:

(1) From [Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), for any $x$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $x < p < 2x$

(2) Base Case: $7\# = 210 \ge (14)^2 + (14) = 210$

(3) Assume for a prime $p \ge 7$, $p\# \ge (2p)^2 + (2p)$

(4) Let $p+c$ be the lowest prime greater than $p$ so that from step 1 above, $2 \le c < p$

(5) $(2p+2c)^2 + 2(p+c) = (4p^2+2p+2c) + 8pc + 4c^2 < (4p^2 + 4p) +  (8p^2 + 8p) + (4p^2 + 4p) < 2p\# + 4p\#+ 2p\# = (2+4+2)p\# < (p+c)p\#$

Comment: What you've done looks correct. It's fairly obvious that $x\#$ grows much faster than $x^2 + x$, such as shown in the table in Wikipidea's [Primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial). However, as for proving the inequality mathematically, I don't know of any method which is particularly simpler or more straight-forward than what you've used. My only minor comment is there is small  descrepency between your title, which uses $x\# \gt x^2 + x$, and your question statement of $x\# \ge x^2 + x$.

Comment: Thanks, John!  I had originally planned to prove the tighter version.  I'll update the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is pretty good, but I feel the solution was difficult to read. I will just rephrase your ideas more clearly. 
1) Claim: It is enough to prove that $p\#\geq (2p)^2+2p$ for $p$ prime.

Indeed, let $x$ any natural number, then we can find  $p_{n}\leq x<p_{n+1}$. By Bertrand postulate, we have $ p_{n+1}<2p_n$. Hence,
$$x\#=p_{n}\#\geq (2p_n)^2+(2p_n)\geq x^2+x.$$
2) We are going to prove the claim by induction:

Case p=7 is easy to check.

Assume hypothesis for $p_n$, let's prove it for $p_{n+1}$: 
Recall $p_{n+1}\leq 2p_n$. Then, we have$$ (2p_{n+1})^2+(2p_{n+1})\leq (4p_n)^2+4p_n\leq 4((2p_n)^2+(2p_n))\leq 4p_n\#\leq p_{n+1}\#$$
Which is what we wanted to prove.